# CSS - Bootstrap - Header wider than the page in Mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am testing a free Bootstrap template, and I can't fix an issue that I've found with it: the Header element appears to be wider than the page content, and makes a scrollbar appear at the page, when viewed in a Mobile (400x283) viewport (in Chrome Developer Tools):
https://distracted-jepsen-8ac7db.netlify.app/

Template code: https://github.com/tonysepia/so-theme

I have gone through the following steps to investigate the problem:

- Used the Element Selection tool in Developer tools to identify the exact element that is causing the page to grow wide:
  [image]
- The offender is within the `<header>` tag, as expected

However, none of the Styles that I disable in the Developer Console seem to be able to remove the scrollbar at the bottom of the page!

**Questions:** What is the next step in troubleshooting such problems, and how can I prevent the header from occupying this extra space and make it align with the page content, without breaking the Desktop view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

hi, i found the issue solution regarding the x axis scroll..its because testimonial slider's navigation buttons are outside the frame ...you can fix this using position:absolute;

Comment: Thank you, great find! To which element have you applied the position;absolute?

Comment: the elements i have shown in the dev tools..you have to position them properly....use position absolute to the marked elements in the above pics..and use left and right props to position them properly

Comment: I have done that, but I am still getting the horizontal scrollbar. Could you please show your change here: https://github.com/tonysepia/so-theme ?

Comment: I just had to refresh the page! You have found the problem successfully, thank you!